# AngularJS show month only for multiple dates of same month

Tags: arrays, angularjs, date

I need to show account statement in month wise instead of dates. I have an array of dates like below;

**Date Array**

```
[
  "2018-12-15T06:36:56",
  "2018-12-14T06:36:56",
  "2018-12-16T06:36:56",
  "2018-12-01T06:36:56",
  "2018-11-13T06:36:56",
  "2018-11-01T06:36:56"
]
```

based on above example, I'm able to loop through each one and show show respectively in human readable format. But i want to show only one month if has multiple dates.

**----P.S----**

I'm able to filter above array into "Month & Year format (MM-YYYY)" and I'm getting response in console as well. But I'm facing issue passing this array outside of forEach loop.

Mean, If i console this within loop than i get correct response in array shape. But after outside of loop i can see only last string of array object.

Further please check [plunkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/2KuPZbqL885iOakNlYwJ)

Comment: ok so what's the problem? you can filter it out by month and get the data

Comment: I don't understand. Are you referring to adding this filter in ng-repeat? Or in controller?

Comment: I've added plunker demo and code can be see in script.js on line 7 to 32

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, after banging head against wall and some luck I managed to accomplish it.

First i modified array with filtered "month-year" format with below loop.

```
$scope.statementListRespone = [
  "2018-12-15T06:36:56",
  "2018-12-14T06:36:56",
  "2018-12-16T06:36:56",
  "2018-12-01T06:36:56",
  "2018-11-13T06:36:56",
  "2018-11-01T06:36:56"
]

var listOutput = $scope.statementListRespone;
var outputList = [];

angular.forEach(listOutput, function(type, $index) {
  output = $filter('date')(listOutput[$index], "MMM yyyy");

  if (output.indexOf(type) === -1) {
    // push this item to our final output array
    outputList.push(output);
  }
});
$scope.outputListFiltered = outputList;
```

This will give us result like below;

**outputList: Modified Array**

```
[
  "Oct 2018",
  "Nov 2018",
  "Nov 2018",
  "Dec 2019",
  "Dec 2019",
  "Dec 2019",
  "Dec 2019"
]
```

Than on view part, I updated loop code with following on line 27 (of plunkr);

**View**

```
<tr ng-repeat="stateItem in sortedType = (outputListFiltered | unique)">
```

Note: i used angular.filter library for filtering unique values.